# How to travel between points in Grand Canyon when there is no shuttle?

Tags: usa, hiking, national-parks, grand-canyon, arizona

If one goes on a loop hike [South Kaibab - Bright Angel Campground - Indian Garden - South Rim](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/South+Kaibab+Trailhead,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ+86023/Bright+Angel+Campground,+N+Kaibab+Trail,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ+86023/Indian+Garden+Campground,+Bright+Angel+Trail,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Bright+Angel+Trailhead,+Bright+Angel+Trail,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/@36.0570109,-112.1268496,13.81z/data=!4m26!4m25!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331079f83ee3c7:0xb2d16755e4162e26!2m2!1d-112.0839461!2d36.0529569!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331109e7b5da47:0x4bc824644ee4e0b6!2m2!1d-112.096154!2d36.1017877!1m5!1m1!1s0x873310ce653f5981:0xddd20180eae036ec!2m2!1d-112.1287741!2d36.0775316!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331735570246ef:0x864e99540608b624!2m2!1d-112.1436384!2d36.0573002!3e2) or even takes [Rim Trail](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Grand+Canyon+Visitor+Center,+South+Entrance+Road,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Yavapai+Point/Trail+View+Point/Maricopa+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Powell+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Hopi+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/The+Abyss,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Pima+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Hermit's+Rest+Viewpoint,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/@36.0696911,-112.2005082,12.52z/data=!4m56!4m55!1m5!1m1!1s0x8733109224db22ad:0xc96303cc4e475ee2!2m2!1d-112.1093081!2d36.0591626!1m5!1m1!1s0x873310ea49a13961:0xb4431b28280c019c!2m2!1d-112.1166801!2d36.0660209!1m5!1m1!1s0x873317327dbd4fbf:0x4e81f8d219c42870!2m2!1d-112.146986!2d36.0619162!1m5!1m1!1s0x8733172c571f885f:0x995a688a9492670b!2m2!1d-112.1462809!2d36.0699828!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331728e0b18db3:0x771a75c855a891ab!2m2!1d-112.1512208!2d36.0732299!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331727f0153709:0xee2d7e59eea3af89!2m2!1d-112.1549472!2d36.0744361!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331716703c44e7:0xf3842021e12caff7!2m2!1d-112.1691254!2d36.0581204!1m5!1m1!1s0x8733165229d01917:0x19487075f5a357c7!2m2!1d-112.2001712!2d36.0719269!1m5!1m1!1s0x873317b5b9a236bb:0x5c6ec84be4b778b8!2m2!1d-112.21248!2d36.06076!3e2) in the wintertime when the shuttles are not operating, how do they return to their car (which is presumably parked near the point where the hike originated)? Is walking or taking Uber/Lyft (is Uber/Lyft operating in Grand Canyon?) the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk or drive. If you're doing a point-to-point walk, then having two cars is helpful: drop off one at the end point of your walk, using the other car to drive to the start point.

I doubt there's enough demand for uber/lyft at the Grand Canyon for there to be any cars operating there.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there were a few Uber/Lyft drivers working at the Grand Canyon in the height of the tourist season (i.e., the summer), but I agree that there probably won't be any there in the winter.